# Why does truffle console not start?

Tags: truffle, truffle-config

Trying to follow the tutorial on Medium, I would like to open the truffle console (Ubuntu 16.04).

I get the following output:

```
mzh@021-voting $ truffle console
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:116:32)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:544:12)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:414:24)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1281:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
mzh@021-voting $
mzh@021-voting $ npm -version
3.10.10

mzh@021-voting $ truffle -version
Truffle v3.1.1 - a development framework for Ethereum

Usage: truffle <command> [options]

Commands:
  init      Initialize new Ethereum project with example contracts and tests
  compile   Compile contract source files
```

Can't find any information about problems with the truffle console on the web. Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: my `truffle -version` returns `Truffle v3.4.9`, maybe it's just a matter of updating it?

Comment: I actually downdated it to be in sync with the tutorial, but I'll try

Comment: Nice, truffle 3.4.11 works. Also testrpc is running concurrently. Seems to be required.

Comment: yes, truffle console needs an eth client (testrpc or geth or similar) to send its commands to. With truffle 4.0 the plan is to have a sort of minimal testrpc bundled with truffle so you do not need to install anything else for testing purposes. See https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases for more info.